# Not able to Create Quick Action on Service Contract object

Tags: lightning, quickaction, service

Not able to create lightning quick action on standard Service Contract object. Does anybody has some information on it?

Answer (score 3):

**Supported Objects**

```
You can create object-specific actions only on these objects: 
• Account 
• Campaign 
• Case 
• Contact
• Group 
• Lead 
• Opportunity 
• All Custom objects
```

Note:- Even Global action are also not be available for Service Contracts object.

Only option you left with is try calling the Lightning Component inside a visualforce Page and Create button with using that VF page.